# check for appended object and add function to that object

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, modal-dialog, append

I've made a modal inside WooCommerce, which displays succes messages and such. I have a problem with the closing of the modal. When the page loads, the modal doesn't exist yet. So I can't apply js to it. How can I apply the function after the modal is appended?

This is what i've tried (in coffeescript):

```
#closing the modal
  if $('.modal-close').length > 0
    close = $('.modal-close')

    close.click (e) ->
      e.preventDefault()

      if $('.modal').length > 0
        $(this).removeClass "modal-active"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation!

The jquery docs have some great info about it [here](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$('body').on('click', '.modal-close', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.modal-active').removeClass('.modal-active');
});
```